# Magento 1.9 - Why different Product URL for different Store

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have 1 website, 2 stores, and 1500 products.
All products assigned to both stores.

Why every product has different URL for each store?

I tried to `truncate core_url_rewrite table` and re-index again. But still, each product has different URL for the store.

Ex:

Product = ABC (SKU = ABC)

Product URL in Store1: abc.html

Product URL in store2: abc-1.html

Comment: Have you save diffrent sku from diffrent store by unchecking the checkbox at store level?

Comment: No, SKU is same on both stores.

Comment: Can you share the screen-sort?